# How to change text on gtk.label in frequent intervals - PyGTK

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I am coding a desktop application which shows contents from text file in a gtk.label, i update that text file, say once in every 15 mints. Are are there any methods to make the application to read the text file in constant intervals and display it without restarting the window

Comment: Does that have to be portable? If not, what OS do you target?

Comment: i am running gnome+ubuntu, will be good enough if its portable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On all platforms, you can call [gobject.timeout_add()](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/gobject-functions.html#function-gobject--timeout-add) to read the file every once in a while, or [gobject.idle_add()](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/gobject-functions.html#function-gobject--idle-add) with an mtime check to do it when the app is idle.

On linux, I'd recommend using [pyinotify](http://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify) to monitor the file and re-read it only when it's updated.

Comment: hey! thanks for the quick solution.. i was just going through timeout_add() :)